# Ormlitehelper used to created two databases

Tags: database, ormlite, temporary

I had requirement in my project where I required to create a database and temporary database(just "temp_" appended to name of database).

lets say I had a database already created in my assets folder with name "sample.db" and when my application loads on splash I copy that database from assets and paste it into package-name/databases folder.Now I fire a request to check if new data is present in , If new data is there then I created temporary database "temp_sample.db" with all the tables as sample.db.Then populate that database and rename it to sample.db finally deleting original sample.db.

I had to read from sample.db before creating temp_sample.db. So i created one constructor with DB_NAME = "sample.db" and Then I used sample helper class to create database with DB_NAME = "temp_sample.db" ofcourse with another overloaded constructor.Now I am using single class with two instances pointing to different databases because all the tables in both databases is same.One instance for reading and one for writing.

Please suggest if there is any other technique to handle this kind of situation in ormlite.Please point out any problems with this current scenario.

Thank you,

Comment: Does it work?  If not please provide details about how it is failing.

Comment: Hello , Currently it is working fine. I was just asking if you see any flaw in this method so that I can rectify that.